# rails flash alert message will close only on sign in page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash, devise

I am looking primarily to get the rest of the app pages to automatically close the flash messages that are displayed. It only occurs on the sign-in page where it correctly closes on its own. The rest of the flash alerts shouldn't need to be closed with click.

Maybe some interaction with Devise is throwing this off?

Rails 4.x, Ruby 2.x, Devise

On application.html:

```
<body>

  <%= render partial: 'layouts/navigation' %>

  <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <% if msg.is_a?(String) %>
    <div class="row" style="max-width:500px;">
      <div data-alert class="alert-box info round <%= name.to_s == 'notice' ? 'success' : 'alert' %>">
        <h3><%= content_tag :div, msg %>
        <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a></h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <%= yield %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>

  </body>
```

On application.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".alert").delay(1000).fadeOut(3000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only fading out when there is an `alert`.  What about when there is a `flash` or a `notice`?  With either of those, the fade out will not happen because the class will not exist.

You set the class based on the type of message that is being shown.

```
<%= name.to_s == 'notice' ? 'success' : 'alert' %>
```

So this will actually only fade out when it is an alert.

Try surrounding the entire thing in a div with the class `message`.

```
<body>

<%= render partial: 'layouts/navigation' %>

<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
<% if msg.is_a?(String) %>
  <div class="row" style="max-width:500px;">
    <div class="message">
      <div data-alert class="alert-box info round <%= name.to_s == 'notice' ? 'success' : 'alert' %>">
        <h3><%= content_tag :div, msg %>
        <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a></h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Then change your javascript to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".message").delay(1000).fadeOut(3000);
```

This will fade out anything with the class message and it won't matter if the stuff inside has a class of alert, flash, or notice.  They will all do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Is this what you mean by "surround the entire thing"?

Comment: <% if msg.is_a?(String) %><div class="message">
    <div class="row" style="max-width:500px;">
      <div data-alert class="alert-box info round <%= name.to_s == 'notice' ? 'success' : 'alert' %>">
        <h3><%= content_tag :div, msg %>
        <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a></h3>
      </div>
    </div></div>
  <% end %>

Comment: I just updated my answer with an example of what I meant by "surround the entire thing".  Take a look at the placement of the <div> with the class `message`.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks so much Mike

Comment: No problem.  Glad to hear it!